# Entire page response to string?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

In beanshell is it possible to dump the contents of the entire page into a String?

Something like:

```
String entirePage = vars.get(entire-page)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it in [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor), it has `data` pre-defined variable which stands for byte array containing parent sampler response.

So something like:

```
String entirePage = new String(data);
vars.put("entire-page", entirePage);
```

should do the trick for you.

Another approach you can take is using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor). As per [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) guide regular expression which matches literally everything will look as `(?s)(^.*)`

Comment: I just tried this but it wrote nothing to file:    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\downloads\\results.txt", true);
    String entirePage = new String(data);
    
    out.write(entirePage);

    out.close();